# Get Current User when creating record . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I have a field many2one relation to res.users in point of sale like this :

```
  user_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.users', string='Responsible',
        help="Person who uses the cash register. It can be a reliever, a student or an interim employee.",
        default=lambda self: self.env.uid,
        states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'invoiced': [('readonly', True)]},
    )

<field string="User" name="user_id"/>
```

I want to set it 'required' and empty field , but when saving record if the value of 'user_id' was empty , then get the current user.
I tried with this code , but required value was blocking:

```
@api.model
    def _default_user_id(self):
        if not self.user_id:
            self.user_id = self.env.uid
        else:
            self.user_id = False


    user_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.users',
        required=True,
        help="Person who uses the cash register. It can be a reliever, a student or an interim employee.",
        default=_default_user_id,
        states={'done': [('readonly', True)], 'invoiced': [('readonly', True)]},
    )
```

How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your default code

from

> default=lambda self: self.env.uid,

to

> default=lambda self: self.env.user,

**EDIT-1**

In this case, we need to override `create()` method instead of write logic in default function. With following code, it will check `user_id` field at the time of record create, if record doesn't have user_id, it will set current logged user.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if "user_id" not in vals:
        vals.update({"user_id": self.env.user})
    record = super().create(vals)
    return record
```

**EDIT-2**

In this case, we need to write down default function.

```
def _default_user_id(self):
    if not self.user_id:
        return self.env.user
    return False
```

Comment: My question is about adding required = True,
Get value empty by default
When saving record, if user_id was empty, then getting the current user_id

Comment: I updated the post by adding the  actual code @Bhavesh Odedra

Comment: can the field be required ?? , because always blocking message of required field.

Comment: @K.ju Try `Edit-2` solution.

Comment: In this case, the value of user_id get the current user by default , I need to get empty value by default,  @Bhavesh Odedra